# Using differential evolution in parallel with joblib.parallel

Tags: python

My intention is to execute the following code in parallel:

```
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution

bounds = [(0,2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2)]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds)

print(result)
```

For that purpose I'm trying the `parallel` method in the `joblib` library. So,

```
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

bounds = [(0,2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2)]

a= Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(differential_evolution)((rosen, bounds)))
print(a)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. In almost all the examples that I can understand, they have one variable functions. So I'm finding it very confusing to implement this `differential_evolution` optimization method to minimize the Rosenbrock function in parallel.

Appreciate your help

Comment: If all you have is one function call, then it can't be parallelized.  Parallelization only happens when you have one function that is called with a set of different parameters.

Comment: Let me change my response.  The `differential_evolution` function has the ability to parallelize itself:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the response. Your first comment helped me to realize that you need several independent calculations for the joblib to work.... and by the way, for the `workers` parameter also I'm getting an error when executing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475817/error-when-executing-the-workers-parameter-in-scipy-differential-evolution